# Optimizing Compare of 2 mysql JSON columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

This is really a part 2 of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77385473/comparing-2-mysql-json-datatype-columns) question.
I have two tables, each with a JSON column.

However the tables have over a million records, and the JSON objects are quite big.

I am performing a comparison to see which objects are in the second table, which either aren't in the first, or are something in the JSON changed.
The two tables have a key ID column, and the JSON column.
So new key IDs appearing in the second table, are obviously new records.
But if the key ID is in both tables, then I need to know if the object has changed.

Normally I perform this sort of Delta compare using a checksum of the fields in table, and compare to the same records of the other table, and the differences are quickly found by simple compare of the checksum.

However, because these are JSON objects, I cannot create a checksum, since the order of the keys is not guaranteed to be consistant within the object... But the objects should be considered equal.
So I am really just comparing 2 objects directly.
This seems to take far too long.

Are there better ways to compare 2 JSON columns?
(Other than ensuring the keys are in the same order on both table's JSONs, and then converting to text and creating a checksum..)

I utilize JSON_OBJECT to build my objects.. But I suppose its not really about how the JSON objects are built, since they are stored in the JSON datatype - its more about a consistant way they will be extracted to compare against.    So I guess I should also mention that table 1 gets created , and it might be months before table 2 is.. so I suppose the worry on creating checksums is that the mySQL method of extracting the JSON may change in between those times, and cause the process to suddenly think all the records have changed...(assuming table 1 is created with checksums in it, rather than holding the JSON)

I suppose I could just leave the checksums to happen at the same time, and therefore mySQL can change their ordering anytime, and I should be fine, assuming whatever they do, it is consistent with each call.

But let me know if there are other methods out there that are slick

Comment: Please read the description of the tags [tag:json] and [tag:mysql-json]. Use the latter for use of JSON in MySQL.

Comment: Please describe how you are building the JSON arrays, and why you can't ensure the order is consistent. Arrays preserve the order you define when you create the JSON document. Object keys become ordered alphabetically (unless you store JSON in a TEXT column or something, instead of a JSON column).

Comment: Is it essential that the data be in MYSQL format?  Because MongoDB is designed from the ground up to support JSON objects, and MYSQL is still getting constant updates to support it.

Comment: @BillKarwin, the arrays will preserve order, yes.   The keys only become ordered (by length, not alpha, as far as I'm aware) due to the current way mySQL does it, but they do not commit to that method for any future release.. Not to mention that JSON does not define the order as needing to be consistent. So i don't want to build my delta around that order

Comment: Okay, then forget about JSON for purposes of the checksum calculation. Don't calculate the checksum based on the resulting JSON document, but on your own logic for the set of keys and values. You can still store the data as JSON, but the checksum is based on something you define.

Comment: Consider providing a short example.